# css/ js: How to display on click on a button the rest of the paragraph text while being responsive?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to display the rest of my text with an animation on the height when you click on a button, I managed to do it but the problem is that I can't find a way to make it responsive.. Basically I display a height: 30px and an overflow: hidden.

And I toggle on a class that contains a height: 300px , it looks good in the mobile version but if I increase the resolution of the page the height will become too small.

I thought there might be a way to adapt the height with the width of the screen, or maybe there is another way to hide part of the text?

Below is the code:

Scss:

```css
.about__body{
    @include displayFlex($direction: column, $align-item: center);
    gap: 20px;
    &-content {
        height: 60px;
        overflow: hidden;
        transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
    }
}

.about__body-content-show {
    transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
    height: auto;
}
```

JS:

```js
let btnAbout = document.getElementById("btn--about")
let contentAbout = document.querySelector(".about__body-content")

const onClickShow = () => {
    btnAbout.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        contentAbout.classList.toggle('about__body-content-show')
    })
}
onClickShow()
```

Comment: can you post your html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically can use JS to achieve this and make your container same height as your content

```
document.getElementById('expand').addEventListener('click', function() {
     document.querySelector('.content-holder').style.height = document.querySelector('.content').offsetHeight + 'px';
     document.querySelector('.content-holder').classList.toggle('collapsed');
});
```

a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sdjhetq1/